# R package OmicsPLS: How to calculate the p1 and p(corr) 1 values from a standard o2m model?

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a series of omics data and got interested in the R package OmicsPLS. It could calculate a standard o2m model by the function "o2m" and build a loading plot like this style (pics are from internet):

[image]

but seems that it will need p1 (modeled covariation of #1 componement) and p(corr)1 (modeled correlation) values to obtain the s_plot and shared and unique structure-plot (SUS-plot). **My question is, is that possible to calculate these values by a standard o2m model? Or should I use other packages to do this?** Any opinions will be much appreciated.

[image]

############################### edit #################################

Here is the example code I use from the r package:

```
test_X <- scale(matrix(rnorm(100*10),100,10))
test_Y <- scale(matrix(rnorm(100*11),100,11))
fit <- o2m(test_X, test_Y, 3, 2, 1)
```

And the fitting result is a standard o2m model (i.e,a large list). My question is, how to use this list to calculate the p1 and p(corr)1 value to get these plots.

Comment: I am bit lost.. So are you having issues with the package or you have some results from using the package and are having problems producing these plots? Can you share an example with some code, giving a context of what you want to achieve

Comment: Thankss for the reply, let me add some code below. Actually I have no issues with the package itself by now, but having problems producing the p1 and p(corr)1 value in order to producing thses plots.